# powershell cmdlet for system center 2012 end point protection?

Tags: windows, system-center

Anyone knows if there are cmdlets for endpoint protection in system center 2012?

I am trying to force to update definitions for endpoint protection from system center 2012, looks there is no such way to do it. every time if I have a new PC, I have to wait for system center to install the client, I dont know when it will be installed and I can't manually install it myself.

There are ways to make scripts using powershell working with system center, but i dont find cmdlets for end point protection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such cmdlet for that http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj821822(v=sc.20).aspx

But if you export settings for endpoint protection in xml file and place it somewhere in your network you can push installation with powershell in the following way:

```
$computers = Get-Content "C:\computer.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {


#The location of the file  
    $Install = "\\$computer\C$\Software"

#The Install string can have commands aswell
  $InstallString = "$Install\scepinstall.exe /s /q //policy \\share\SCEpolicy\endpoint.xml"

    ([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)
#Output the install result to your Local C Drive
    Out-File -FilePath c:\installed.txt -Append -InputObject "$computer"}
```

By default both scepintall.exe and policy are located at C:\Sources on SCCM.